# how use pefile to check for NX, ASLR, SAFESEH and CFG (Control Flow Guard) flag

Tags: windows, pe, protection

i use `pefile` library for help me in vulnerability research,malware analysis  and exploit development and try to write script help me to know which protections binary use

i know `mona.py` from corelan team but i just need to write some tools will help me without use mona `because i'm not use immunity debugger i use python debugger`

====update=========
i wrote this script

```
import os.path
import sys
import pefile

class PESecurityCheck:

  IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE = 0x0040
  IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT = 0x0100
  IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_SEH = 0x0400
  IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_GUARD_CF = 0x4000



  def __init__(self,pe):
    self.pe = pe

  def aslr(self):
    return bool(self.pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.DllCharacteristics & self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE)

  def dep(self):
    return bool(self.pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.DllCharacteristics & self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT)

  def seh(self):
    return bool(self.pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.DllCharacteristics & self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_SEH)

  def CFG(self):
    return bool(self.pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.DllCharacteristics & self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_GUARD_CF)

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  print 'Usage: %s <file_path>' % sys.argv[0] 
  sys.exit()

def main():
  file_path = sys.argv[1]   

  try:
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
      pe = pefile.PE(file_path,True)
    else:
      print "File '%s' not found!" % file_path     
      sys.exit(0)  
  except pefile.PEFormatError:
    print "Not a PE file!"
    sys.exit(0)  

  ps = PESecurityCheck(pe)

  if ps.aslr():
    print "[+] ASLR Enabled"
  else:
    print "[-] ASLR Not Enabled"

  if ps.dep():
    print "[+] DEP Enabled"
  else:
    print "[-] DEP Not Enabled"

  if ps.seh():
    print "[+] SEH Enabled"
  else:
    print "[-] SEH Not Enabled"

  if ps.CFG():
    print "[+]CFG Enabled"
  else:
    print "[-] CFG Not Enabled"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NX:**

`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.DllCharacteristics & IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT != 0`

**ASLR:**

`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.DllCharacteristics & IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE != 0`

**SAFESEH:**

`(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG].VirtualAddress != 0)
&& (IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG].Size != 0 )`

**CFG:**

`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.DllCharacteristics & IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_GUARD_CF != 0`